# Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\ln^2 n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\ln k}{k} $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\ln^2 n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\ln k}{k} $$
I do understand, that we can write this as:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\ln k}{\ln^2 n} \cdot \frac{1}{k}$$
$$\frac{\ln k}{\ln^2 n} = \frac{\ln k}{\ln n} \cdot \frac{1}{\ln n} = \frac{\log_{n}k}{\ln n}$$
$\log_{a}b = \frac{1}{\log_{b}a}$, so
$$\frac{\log_{n}k}{\ln n} = \log_{n}k \log_{n}e$$
Hence, $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\ln^2 n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\ln k}{k}  = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \log_{n}k \log_{n}e $$

For sufficiently large $n$ $\log_{n}e$ will tend to zero, while $\log_{n}k \to 1, k \to n$
So if there is no mistake, my best guess that this limit is equal $1$. But I can't prove it. Any help?

Also, can we use Stolz–Cesàro theorem for this?

Comment: Also you can try and use some asymptotics. For example $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\ln(k)}{k}\sim \frac{\ln^{2}(n)}{2}$ . That is we are using $\int_{1}^{x}\frac{\ln(x)}{x}\,dx=\frac{\ln^{2}(x)}{2}$

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron hence limit $\sim$ $\frac{1}{2}$? Interesting result. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah the limit is $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Stolz–Cesàro works as well: $$
\frac{{\frac{{\log (n + 1)}}{{n + 1}}}}{{\log ^2 (n + 1) - \log ^2 n}} = \frac{n}{{n + 1}}\frac{{1/n}}{{\log (1 + 1/n)}}\frac{{\log (n + 1)}}{{\log (n + 1) + \log n}} \to 1 \cdot 1 \cdot \frac{1}{2}
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Stolz–Cesàro theorem:
$$\frac{{\frac{{\log (n + 1)}}{{n + 1}}}}{{\log ^2 (n + 1) - \log ^2 n}} = \frac{n}{{n + 1}}\frac{{1/n}}{{\log (1 + 1/n)}}\frac{{\log (n + 1)}}{{\log (n + 1) + \log n}} \to 1 \cdot 1 \cdot \frac{1}{2}$$

Thanks to Gary